# Pass a string from an Android Java activity to a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver

I have spent the last couple of hours looking through other questions on this topic and none that I found were able to give me any answers.

What is the best way to pass a string from an activity to a broadcast receiver in the background?

Here is my main activity

```
public class AppActivity extends DroidGap {
 SmsReceiver mSmsReceiver = new SmsReceiver();

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    ScrollView scroll;
    scroll = new ScrollView(this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String ownAddress  = bundle.getString("variable");

    registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, new IntentFilter("MyReceiver"));
             Intent intent = new Intent("MyReceiver");
              intent.putExtra("passAddress", ownAddress);
             sendBroadcast(intent);

            Log.v("Example", "ownAddress: " + ownAddress);
 }
}
```

Here is my broadcast receiver

```
public class AppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String ownAddress  = intent.getStringExtra("passAddress");
    Toast test = Toast.makeText(context,""+ownAddress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    test.show();

    Log.v("Example", "ownAddress: " + ownAddress);

 }
}
```

Here is the manifest for my receiver

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:enabled="true"/>
 <receiver android:name="AppReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
 <receiver>
<service android:name=".MyServiceSentReceived" android:enabled="true"/>
 <receiver android:name="AppReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483645">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

When the broadcast receiver logs an event the app crashes. I need to have it run behind the scenes and pull a string from my main activity.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Addition from comments and chat**

Your String `ownAddress` will always be null unless the Intent has an String with the key `passAddress` in the the Bundle extras. Anytime your Receiver catches an Intent (whether from `SMS_SENT`, `SMS_RECEIVED`, or `BOOT_COMPLETED`) `ownAddress` will be null because the OS doesn't provide a String extra named `passAddress`. Hope that clears things up.

**Original Answer**

I haven't used DroidGap but this is what you want for a regular Android Activity.

Activity:

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {
    AppReceiver mAppReceiver = new AppReceiver();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        registerReceiver(mAppReceiver, new IntentFilter("MyReceiver"));

        String string = "Pass me.";
        Intent intent = new Intent("MyReceiver");
        intent.putExtra("string", string);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Receiver:

```
public class AppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("string"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the receiver in onDestroy(), like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mAppReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. While many of the methods have descriptive names, I didn't explain the actions, don't hesitate to ask if you need a little clarification.

Comment: Actually, in my receiver I now have final String ownAddress  = intent.getStringExtra("passAddress"); to catch the passed string but when I use "ownAddress" in my HttpPost it is returned as null. Do you know what could be happening here?

Comment: Please edit this code into your question, so I can see what is happening.

Comment: Ok. I have updated the question with the code I am using now.

Comment: If `ownAddress` is null then whatever Intent starts your Activity simply doesn't have a String associated with the key `"variable"`... How are your starting AppActivity?

Comment: AppActivity is started through a login activity. ownAddress is only null when it is being passed through to the broadcast receiver.

Comment: When the app is open ownAddress is not null but when the app is running in the background ownAddress is null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14962/discussion-between-sam-and-peter-merrill)