# How to update broadcast receiver. (multiple notification)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver, notificationmanager

Variables in BroadcastReceiver are not updating every time i set a notification/alarm manager.

[image]

[image]

"receiver (recycler)" is from a fragment.

receiver" is from a BroadcastReceiver class.

onCreateView

```
intentAlarmManager = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarmManager, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Notification Method

```
    private void setNotification(int hour, int min, int interval, int uniqueID) {

    //get instance of the calendar
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    //create delayed intent
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqueID, intentAlarmManager, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * (interval * 30), pendingIntent);


}
```

Recycler its attached to a switch listener

```
setNotification(Integer.parseInt(model.getHour()), Integer.parseInt(model.getMinute()), Integer.parseInt(model.getInterval()), Integer.parseInt(model.getTime()));
```

Receiver

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intentToStartWhenAlarmSets = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intentToStartWhenAlarmSets, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setContentText("Notify " + HomeFragment.notifMedName)
                .setSound(notifSound)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                //swipable
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "receiver " + HomeFragment.notifMedName);

        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i think. Although I'm not sure if this is the best/correct way (i'ts working though).

So in in my receiver class i added

```
intent.getStringExtra("string);
```

and in my fragment i added

```
intentAlarmManager.putExtra("string", notifMedName);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intentAlarmManager);
```

and also i changed all pending intent from `context` to `getActivity()`.

Feel free to answer if you guys have a better solution.

[More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834742/pass-a-string-from-an-android-java-activity-to-a-broadcast-receiver)